# How to get the correct UTC starting date of friends events (or basically of any event not created by me) through fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the correct start date for events that were not created by me. I understood how facebook saves events starting and ending date ( [Can someone expalin me how facebook stores the start and end time of events?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10600464/can-someone-expalin-me-how-facebook-stores-the-start-and-end-time-of-events)) and i understood that i need to know my timezone to get the correct starting date in UTC, but what about other events?How do i get the timezone of the user who created the event using fql or the graph api?Is there a way?
I'm using the php SDK.
This is the code i use to get events

```
            $fql = "SELECT 
                        eid,
                        name,
                        description,
                        start_time,
                        end_time,
                        venue,
                        location,
                        update_time
                    FROM
                        event
                    WHERE 
                        eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = $id)" ;
            $events = $facebook->api( array(
                'method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' => $fql,
            ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Timezone seems to be restricted to the current user only.

However, you should be able to get the owner->id of the event.  If the owner is a user (person) then you can get the location->id which may yield a lat\long from the place or the location->name.  In either case you still need to do a look up on the location to match it to a timezone.

Also, the location information might not be available unless your access token has friends_location permissions.